# How to transform current date-time into Unix time (Epoch) using AMPscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to have the current date/time outputted as Unix Epoch time (to add to a URL in an email), but there appear to be no functions for this in AMPscript.

Is this possible any other way?

Thanks!!

Comment: Since its the time from 1.1.1970 you could write a script that calculates the seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Ampscript, following the direction from [Johannes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/52639/johannes-schapdick):

```
%%[
SET @epochStart = DateParse('1970/01/01 00:00AM')
SET @minutesSinceEpoch = DateDiff(@epochStart,Now(),'MI')
SET @seconds = 60
SET @secondsSinceEpoch = Multiply(@minutesSinceEpoch,@seconds)
]%%
Hello seconds: %%=v(@secondsSinceEpoch)=%%
```

Do observe this gives you current Epoch timestamp in system timezone (UTC-6)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Epoch time ignores Leap seconds. There are only 27 leap seconds until this date, so the difference is small but do you have any idea if Marketing Cloud does the same? Or would I always be 27 seconds 'in the future' if I use this solution?

Comment: Well - this is a good question, and a valid point. However in your use case (Epoch in URL parameter) I see this not being a huge issue.

Comment: No, and I think with this solution you will also always have a max of 60 secondes differences with the 'true' Epoch (since you get the minutes since Epoch and multiply by 60).

Comment: I was doing the exact same answer as you did but didn't exactly knew how to set 1970 ;) Haven't used dateparse that much. :D